# Extracting .unity3d files from Unity 3.4.2 for upgrade to Unity 5.2.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to upgrade a project from an old Unity version to a less-old Unity version:

- Original Unity version: 3.4.2 (released October 2011)
- Target Unity version: 5.2.3 (released November 2015)

(FYI, the reason why I am not upgrading to a more recent version of Unity is due to a dependency on a third-party library, Active Reader, and 5.2.3 is the highest version it is compatible with.)

The issue that I'm facing is that in the older Unity, project assets were dealt with in a completely different file format -- .unity3d. I need to extract and/or convert these files in order to be used in the newer Unity version. I do have access to a hard drive containing many versions of the original files, but the file organization is a mess, so it isn't obvious which folders are necessary.

I understand these files were never designed to be extracted (e.g. to prevent piracy) -- but I have found a few tools and threads online about potential processes/solutions: ([Link1](https://gameart.eu.org/reverse-engineering-decompiling-unity3d-files/), [Link2](https://answers.unity.com/questions/185587/extract-files-from-build-or-unbuild.html), [Unity Assets Explorer](http://forum.xentax.com/blog/?p=1046), [DevX Unity Unpacker](http://devxdevelopment.com/UnityUnpacker), [Unity Assets Bundle Extractor (UABE)](https://github.com/DerPopo/UABE), [Disunity experimental tools](https://github.com/ata4/disunity)) Problem is that many of this information is years out of date by this point, has broken links, and/or references very specific Unity versions. Does anyone have any experience with doing something similar, and could help point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: instead of "jumping" over 4 years you could try to upgrade step-wise from version to version. This takes longer and requires the according Unity Versions but it might work more stabel than making such a huge jump

Comment: Start with source files, not compiled output files.